# UITableView cell reverting to old data after [tableview reloadData] is called

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that has several cells of various heights.  Each of the cells has itself a table of cells (here i am manually handling adding and deleting UIViews) that can be edited or deleted. The problem is that any time I edit one of the inner UIViews in one of the UITableViewCells, it is immediately reset to its original data that was given to it at instantiation when i call [tableView reloadData] on the tableview.  If I don't call reload data, all the data looks great, but the height of the row is too large if i happened to have deleted a row from my UITableViewCell class.  I've tried everything I can imagine, calling setNeedsDisplay, removing and re-adding to subview, and creating the cell every time, without using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.  None of these have done the trick.

Any idea what could possibly be going wrong??

Thanks so much!

Comment: You're making some sort of basic mistake, but it's hard to tell what.  My best guess is that you're reusing cells without resetting the data in them first, possibly due to a variable name mixup or some such.

Comment: I suspect he's updating the cells but not updating the underlying data source so a call to reloadData will refresh the cell with the old data :)

Comment: all the data sources are being updated -- i know because when i call reloadData, the cells shrink because they were updated to remove the deleted cell -- however, the data itself doesnt change.

Comment: You were right -- the datasource wasn't getting updated.  I WAS updated the core data reference to the data source INSIDE the cell, but I needed to do it outside of the cell from the call the contains the UITableView too.  Thanks!